# passing file to ec2 in cloud formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have a cloudfromation script that creates some ec2 instances, and later attaches them to an ELB.

I have a python server script written that I would like to have on the ec2 as soon as they are created.
Right now what I do is after the cloudformation script finishes, I use SCP to pass the script to the ec2 instances.

I was wondering if there was a way to do this within the cloudfromation, mabe under UserData?

I should point out I am very new to cloud formation. I have gone over the documentation, but have not been able to do this yet.

[EDIT] I think its important to state that I have a deploy.sh script that I run to create the stack. the script sits in the dame dir as my python server script. I AM NOT USING THE AWS CONSOLE.

this is my instance code in the cloudformation script:

```
EC2Instance2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
      SecurityGroupIds: 
        - !Ref InstanceSecurityGroup
      KeyName: !Ref KeyName
      ImageId: !Ref LatestAmiId
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: 
          !Sub |
            #!/bin/bash
            sleep 20
            sudo apt-get update
            sudo apt-get install python3-pip -y
            sudo apt-get install python3-flask -y
```

Comment: @Marcin in the end i cloned the git repo, as using s3 in my case was not an option - it would lengthen the whole process by a lot. Cloning was the best option.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if there was a way to do this within the cloudfromation, mabe under UserData?

Yes, UserData would be the way to do it. For that you could store your file in S3. For that to work you would need to add [instance role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html) to your instance with S3 permissions. The you would use AWS CLI to copy your file from S3 to the instance.

Comment: so you are saying there is no way to actually pass the file in user data, but rather to retrieve it from s3?

Comment: @ShaiB If its not to large, you can hardcode the entire file in the userdata.